# How to put SetInputFilter DEFLATE in httpd.conf file of Apache so to decompress the Gzip compressed request body

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, gzip, mod-deflate

I am running a java application with tomcat as servlet container and Apache as web server and have Made the connection between these two using APJ connector.
I am making a http post request to this server and the body of request is Gzip compressed. Wanted to decompress the request body using Apache configuration. 
By reading some blogs, I got to know that by using **SetInputFilter DEFLATE** in the httpd.conf file the decompression of request body can be done but it's not happening actually.

```
#Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
#
# Note: The following must must be present to support
#       starting without SSL on platforms with no /dev/random equivalent
#       but a statically compiled-in mod_ssl.
#
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

Include "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.5/conf/mod_jk.conf"

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    SetInputFilter DEFLATE
</IfModule>
```

What is the mistake that I am making, Can someone please let me know.